# convert TSql command to LINQ with error "cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression"

Tags: c#, sql, linq

The following command returns the expected output in SQL Server :

```
select count(*) As CountField 
from
    (select Eductionals.UserID , Max(Eductionals.MaghtaeID) As IDmaghta
from Eductionals 
    group by Eductionals.UserID) Temptable
        inner join MaghtaeTahsilis ON
         Temptable.IDmaghta = MaghtaeTahsilis.ID
        where Temptable.IDmaghta = 3 /* any number */
        group by Temptable.IDmaghta
```

I tried to convert the above code to LINQ :

```
    var maghtae = _maghtaeTahsili.Where(z => z.Code == MaghtaeCode).FirstOrDefault();
    return _eductional.GroupBy(z=> z.UserID).Max().Where(z => z.MaghtaeID == maghtae.ID).Select(z => z).Count();
```

After running, I encounter the following error:

> 'IGrouping' does not contain a definition for
>   'MaghtaeID' and no accessible extension method 'MaghtaeID' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'IGrouping' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You are using Max() which returns a singleton and the Where need a list object.

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) would help you.